# Scroll items in listview android

Tags: android

I am using two `ListView` first is the main `ListView` and inside the first row of `ListView` I am adding the other items of `ListView`, now the problem is according to the values the `ListView` is not scrollable, while I am scroll I am facing runtime exception

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
```

I searched for the problem and I got to know that I have to call `notifydatasetchanged` after adding the values in adapter, but then too scroll view is not managed in `ListView`. Please Help